# Find empty positions in a grid

Tags: oracle11g, set-theory

In a `Contents` table, items are stored in X,Y coordinates:

```
Contents
-------
id
parent_id
pos_x
pos_y
```

Assume the container size is 3 by 3. I'd like to find which positions in a given container are free. So far I've generated a 2D matrix:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT rownum X FROM dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ) xaxis
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT rownum Y FROM dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=3 ORDER BY 1) yaxis
ON xaxis.X <> yaxis.Y OR xaxis.X = yaxis.Y
```

Then I attempt to `JOIN` the queries together, excluding X,Y positions present in `Contents`:

```
SELECT X, Y
FROM 
    (SELECT rownum X FROM dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ) xaxis
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT rownum Y FROM dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=3 ORDER BY 1) yaxis
ON xaxis.X <> yaxis.Y OR xaxis.X = yaxis.Y

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pos_x, pos_y FROM Contents WHERE parent_id = ?) items
ON items.posx <> xaxis.X AND items.posy <> yaxis.Y;
```

This doesn't treat each pair as unique, and excludes values from *all* rows if a position is occupied. For example, assuming that `(2, 2)` is occupied, the above returns:

```
X   Y
-----
1   1
1   3
3   1
3   3
```

Essentially I'm trying to get the difference of the two sets. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @bradimus Backend is Java, but you're right it should be removed. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer right before I posted the question, so I thought I'd post it and answer it at the same time. Stating the problem as *get the difference of the two sets* set me in the right direction.

The answer is the [`MINUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator. Replace the final `JOIN` with `MINUS` and you get the intended results:

```
select X, Y
from 
    (select rownum X from dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 ) xaxis
inner join 
    (select rownum Y from dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=3 order by 1) yaxis
on xaxis.X <> yaxis.Y OR xaxis.X = yaxis.Y

MINUS

select pos_x, pos_y FROM Contents WHERE parent_id = ?;
```

which returns the intended result (note the lack of `(2, 2)`):

```
X   Y
-----
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   3
3   1
3   2
3   3
```

Today was a good day

Comment: I think your inner join should just be a cross join? And, there's no need for the `order by 1` in the yaxis subquery

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an outer join rather than a minus (although you'd have to test both to find out which is more performant for your data!).

If you are only doing it for a single parent_id at a time, you would do:

```
WITH CONTENTS AS (SELECT 1 parent_id, 2 pos_x, 2 pos_y FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 parent_id, 2 pos_x, 1 pos_y FROM dual)
SELECT xaxis.x,
       yaxis.y
FROM   ((SELECT LEVEL x FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) xaxis
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL y FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) yaxis)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENTS c ON c.pos_x = xaxis.x AND c.pos_y = yaxis.y AND c.parent_id = 1
WHERE  c.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY x, y;

         X          Y
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         2          1
         2          3
         3          1
         3          2
         3          3
```

Alternatively, if you want to run it for all parent_ids, you could use a [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) like so:

```
WITH CONTENTS AS (SELECT 1 parent_id, 2 pos_x, 2 pos_y FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 parent_id, 2 pos_x, 1 pos_y FROM dual)
SELECT c.parent_id,
       xaxis.x,
       yaxis.y
FROM   ((SELECT LEVEL x FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) xaxis
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL y FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) yaxis)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENTS c PARTITION BY (c.parent_id) ON c.pos_x = xaxis.x AND c.pos_y = yaxis.y
WHERE  c.pos_x IS NULL
AND    c.pos_y IS NULL
ORDER BY c.parent_id,
         xaxis.x,
         yaxis.y;

 PARENT_ID          X          Y
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         1          1          2
         1          1          3
         1          2          1
         1          2          3
         1          3          1
         1          3          2
         1          3          3
         2          1          1
         2          1          2
         2          1          3
         2          2          2
         2          2          3
         2          3          1
         2          3          2
         2          3          3
```